# How to prepare django migrations?

Tags: python, django, database-migration

Migrating data in django involves two steps:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

The first step prepares the migrations which, as far as I know, are database specific; that is, depending on what database backend you are going to use, you will get different migrations.

If in development I use `sqlite`, and in production `postgres`, does that mean that the migrations that I prepare in development will not work for the production machine?

Comment: Where do you have the information that the migrations are DB dependent from?

Comment: The `makemigration` step is not database specific. If you look at the generated python migration file, you will see that uses abstractions still. Your migrations on sqlite will work on postgres. However, there are differences b/w Postgres and SQLite that will come back to bite later on: for example ORM operations (such as select distinct on field) which are only available in Postgres. Would strongly recommend you use a similar setup in dev/prod.

Comment: Don't push the migration files at production server. Fire `python manage.py makemigrations` command before `python manage.py migrate` This will work Database server specific migration and won't be an issue. Put migrations folder into `.gitignore`

Comment: Usually, the migrations are independent of the type of database you are using. I personally think it would be a good idea to replicate the Prod env on your dev machine.

Comment: @KlausD. probably a misunderstanding on my side ...

Comment: @rtindru understood, thanks

Comment: @AnupYadav so that you suggest is to not commit / deploy the migration files? This is contrary to the practice that I have seen in other projects. Also: how does `makemigrations` work if there are no migrations in the file system? I would say it doesn't. For example: I have seen that removing app/migrations/__init__.py will make `makemigrations` skip this app.

Comment: May be you mis understood or may not be. But system works perfectly in such case, because migrations are based on models. Anyways in your case that solution I could suggest. Even I've not practiced in such way so far, because I haven't found my self in  situation where you caught in.

Comment: @AnapYadav this advice is wrong and dangerous. You must always commit and deploy your migrations. If not, things risk getting out of sync.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for the comment. I understood.

Answer (score 2):

The migrations created by the makemigrations command are not database specific, they can be run on any database.

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate # which displays the SQL statements for a migration
```

From Django Doc :

> Migrations will run the same way on the same dataset and produce
>   consistent results, meaning that what you see in development and
>   staging is, under the same circumstances, exactly what will happen in
>   production

Yes from @Klaus D. comment, I don't think Django have information that the migrations are DB dependent.